# Prevent alertdialog close when none of the buttons are clicked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am developing an application using alertdialog. When my app starts i noticed that the user can **prevent** my alertdialog...

**Example**

[image]

if someone click outside of my alertdialog then dialog will disappear... I want to lock my alertdialog, so the user will be forced to choose!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102777/prevent-android-activity-dialog-from-closing-on-outside-touch

Comment: There are tonnes of answers for this on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply

setCancelable(false)

to your AlertDialog.Builder instance.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line to your dialog

```
mdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `false` in cancel method.

```
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Then your progressDialog will not cancel, until you cancel it.