# Why dialog.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false) can not resolve &

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to display popup dialog window.
Dialog created in this function:

```
    protected void showLoginDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
    dialog.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    final EditText edlogin = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.username);
    final EditText edpass = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button btnLogin = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Button btnCancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginlogin = edlogin.getText().toString();
            loginpassword = edpass.getText().toString();
            loginresult = 1;
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginlogin = ""; loginpassword = ""; loginresult = 0;
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

But `dialog.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)` is marked as error with message

> Cannot resolve method setFinishOnTouchOutside(Boolean)

. 
What's wrong?
Main activity of my app extends `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: from which package you are importing Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot resolve method setFinishOnTouchOutside(Boolean)". What's
>   wrong???

Because as see in [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) class no such method available with `setFinishOnTouchOutside` name.

`setFinishOnTouchOutside` method is available in [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)) and FragmentActivity class

To use `setFinishOnTouchOutside` method need to use class Context which is extending Activity or FragmentActivity like:

```
Your_Activity_Name.this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: It's good ! I wrote MainActivity.this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); and have no syntax error. But my dialog disappeared, when I  tap screen out of the dialog borders ... It's wrong.

Comment: Hope this thread answers you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102777/prevent-android-activity-dialog-from-closing-on-outside-touch