# How to Keep AlertDialog on Screen While Network is Not Available

Tags: android, networking

I am using the following code to show an AlertDialog and prompt the user to press "Retry". The dialog should remain on-screen until connection is available. The app works correctly in that when network is unavailable the dialog appears.

```
mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(MainGroupActivity.this);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainGroupActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Not Connected")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.disconnect)
                .setView(mProgressBar)
                .setMessage("You are not connected to the Internet")
                .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Retry connection
                        if(isNetworkAvailable ())
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        mDialog = builder.create();
        if( !isNetworkAvailable() )
            mDialog.show();
```

The problem is that the dialog is dismissed as soon as I touch somewhere on the screen or press Retry! How can I prevent that?

Comment: use this lib compile 'com.github.nikhilborad:basehelp:1.02' it has method nbShowNoInternet().. thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` .

```
 AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
```

But that will prevent only outside touch not Positive or negative button click .  Its AlertDialog's default behavior to dismiss the dialog on any button click whether you call `dismiss()` or not . So if you want to over ride this behavior you have do something like  this.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Not Connected")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_icon)
            .setView(R.layout.item_dialog)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("You are not connected to the Internet");
    final AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button button =  mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Do your validations task here

                }
            });
        }
    });
    mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

setCancelable(false) will work for you.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainGroupActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Not Connected")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.disconnect)
            .setView(mProgressBar)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("You are not connected to the Internet")
            .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //Retry connection
                    if(isNetworkAvailable ())
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setCancelable(false)` on your construction of `alertDialog`.

```
mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(MainGroupActivity.this);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainGroupActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Not Connected")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.disconnect)
                .setView(mProgressBar)
                .setMessage("You are not connected to the Internet")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Retry connection
                        if(isNetworkAvailable ())
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        mDialog = builder.create();
        if( !isNetworkAvailable() )
            mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent dialog box from getting dismissed on back key pressed use this

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

And to prevent dialog box from getting dismissed on outside touch use this

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

for further help take a look at this question:
[Prevent Android activity dialog from closing on outside touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102777/prevent-android-activity-dialog-from-closing-on-outside-touch)