# How to Dialogue box keep open on outside touch

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have dialogue box on my screen. When I touched on screen dialogue box closes. I want dialogue box should not close on outside touch.My code is given below :-

```
public class Dialogue extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialogue);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        displayDialogue();

    }
    private void displayDialogue(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder myDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myDialogue.setMessage("Please check your voice input output settings.It should be ON" );
        TextView messageView = new TextView(this);
        messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        myDialogue.setView(messageView);
        myDialogue.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Dialogue.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = myDialogue.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: set Cancelable to false

Comment: @user2493740 have a habit of upvoting/marking answer as solved for helpful post

Answer (score 3):

setCancelable(boolean cancelable) : 
Sets whether the dialog is cancelable or not. [Read More](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29).

```
myDialogue.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: @user2493740, glad to help. Please mark accepted and upvote valid answer to provide  for future googler. :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set cancelable to false, so that when on touch outside the dialog will remain open as it is.
Try this in your code:

```
myDialogue.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

add this line

```
myDialogue.setCancelable(false);
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

set the cancelable property false

```
private void displayDialogue(){
final AlertDialog.Builder myDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
myDialogue.setMessage("Please check your voice input output settings.It should be ON" );
TextView messageView = new TextView(this);
messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
myDialogue.setView(messageView);

myDialogue.setCancelable(false);

myDialogue.setPositiveButton("OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Dialogue.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});

AlertDialog dialog = myDialogue.create();
dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

inisde `displayDialog()` method after `.setMessage()`, add the below line:

```
myDialogue.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: @user2493740 Do u find the solution??

Answer (score 1):

You probably already got this but for future people this worked for me:
you can override outside touches to do nothing on the dialog as shown in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5831214