# how to set cancellable false to an activity when it is opened as a Dialog?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

hi i have made a n activity in that i open an activity as a Dialog popup on another activity ,SO i g.ot the problem it is of my theme,

```
 <item `name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">@bool/config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>`
```

but i dont know what value should i change inside `"windowCloseOnTouchOutside"` so that i can do my activity dialog set cancellable false..?
My code in theme is as below:

```
 <style name="Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/panel_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">@bool/config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>

        <item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Inverse</item>

        <item name="textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorTertiary">@android:color/tertiary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorTertiaryInverse">@android:color/tertiary_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_dark_disable_only</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@android:color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/primary_text_light_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorHint">@android:color/hint_foreground_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorHintInverse">@android:color/hint_foreground_light</item>
        <item name="textColorSearchUrl">@android:color/search_url_text</item>

        <item name="textAppearanceLarge">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceMedium">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmall">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargeInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceMediumInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium.Inverse</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small.Inverse</item>

        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">10dip</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">10dip</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingStart">10dip</item>
        <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">10dip</item>

        <item name="preferencePanelStyle">@style/PreferencePanel.Dialog</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: add **<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do that in Java coding very easily.
If you have  an **Activity (even if it looks like a Dialog)**, then you should do

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

if you have used Dialog class, you should call

```
dialog.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)
```

if you want to prevent closing it open when the background activity is clicked.

Comment: "setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)" on which object brother?

Comment: If you are poping up a dialog using Dialog class, then `dialogObject.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` otherwise `this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: @umer-sure brother...sure..i frgot it...:)

Comment: But is it possible to click the background items? @UmerFarooq

Comment: setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); prevent outside click but dnt prevent back button click :(

Answer (score 1):

This could help you. It is a way to handle the touch outside event:

[How to cancel an Dialog themed like Activity when touched outside the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650246/how-to-cancel-an-dialog-themed-like-activity-when-touched-outside-the-window/5831214#5831214)

There is a way to get dialog-like "touch outside to cancel" behaviour from an Activity themed as a dialog, though I've not fully investigated whether it has unwanted side effects.

Within your Activity's `onCreate()` method, before creating the view, you're going to set two flags on the window: One to make it 'non-modal', to allow views other than your activity's views to receive events. The second is to receive notification that one of those events has taken place, which will send you an `ACTION_OUTSIDE` move event.

Try as below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make us non-modal, so that others can receive touch events.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    // ...but notify us that it happened.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);

    // Note that flag changes must happen *before* the content view is set.
    setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_view);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // If we've received a touch notification that the user has touched
    // outside the app, finish the activity.
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.getAction()) {
      finish();
      return true;
    }

    // Delegate everything else to Activity.
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
alert.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: it just work perfectly fine with AlertDialog.Builder ,call setCancelable before cereating AlertDilog.