# Get user confirmation before closing a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I have a DialogFragment that allows a user to create a new record. I would like to intercept the close event to test whether they've started inputting any data, and if so prompt them that will lose unsaved changes. I would rather not add a close button, so the user can close the Dialog by clicking anywhere outside it in the screen.

So is there an event that will allow me to cancel the Dialog close action if the user selects not to?

Comment: +1 I have been wondering about this too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5831214/306257) -- make an activity that intercepts all touch events, both inside and outside its bounds, then checks for ACTION_OUTSIDE on captured touch events. Note that that's using a separate activity for the dialog, not a fragment, so if using the fragment is a strict requirement this method won't work for you.