# How to detect when user touch outside the dialog fragment?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I want to perform some tasks when user touch outside the **dialog fragment**. How can I do this?

- In my custmom dialog fragment there's a piece of code to prevent dialog from closing when touch outside:

  getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley : I want to have a mechanism to handle any custom operation when user touch outside dialog not only for the dismissing.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to remove `getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` and use some reflection to leverage `Window`'s hidden method for deciding when to close dialog:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return object : Dialog(activity as Context, theme) {
        override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            if (dialogShouldCloseOnTouch(window, context, event)) {
                // do custom logic
                return true
            } else {
                return super.onTouchEvent(event)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun dialogShouldCloseOnTouch(
    window: Window, 
    context: Context, 
    event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val method = window.javaClass.getMethod("shouldCloseOnTouch", Context::class.java, MotionEvent::class.java)
    return method.invoke(window, context, event) as Boolean
}
```

Comment: @DYS, it doesn't work on some devices. Error: "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.shouldCloseOnTouch"

Comment: @XueQing Could you tell me the Android version of such devices?

Comment: @DYS, Your code is working well on emulator. But I couldn't use the logic because of the such error. My phone has android 10 version.

Comment: @XueQing It could be. In this case you could simply try copy-pasting `Window.shouldCloseOnTouch` to your `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make us non-modal, so that others can receive touch events.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    // ...but notify us that it happened.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);

    // Note that flag changes must happen *before* the content view is set.
    setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_view);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // If we've received a touch notification that the user has touched
    // outside the app, finish the activity.
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.getAction()) {
      //outside touch event
      return true;
    }

    // Delegate everything else to Activity.
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Reference: [Look at the second answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650246/how-to-cancel-an-dialog-themed-like-activity-when-touched-outside-the-window/5831214#5831214)

P.S. In the question he said he has an **activity** with the **dialog theme.**

Comment: question is for dialog fragment and not activity