# Activity doesn't close when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, crosswalk

I have an application that uses crosswalk. I use it in two activities.

1. In this activity, I have a crosswalk view that shows a list of selectable items and when selected launch another activity.
2. In this new activity I open another crosswalk view that runs the selected item from the previous activity.

The issue that I am having is when in the second activity when I press the back button it goes back to a black screen. If I press the back button again, it then closes the activity.

What can I do to close the activity instead of going back to the black screen? This doesn't happen on all items just a few, and with those few I think that a page redirect is happening in crosswalk so when I press back it just goes to the previous screen.

Here is the activity:

```
package com.gamesmart.gamesmart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;

public class Play extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");

        XWalkView xWalkWebView = (XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebViewPlay);

        // Turn on debugging if we are in DEBUG mode
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
        }

        // Load the url
        xWalkWebView.load(url, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        finish();
    }
}
```

I don't think that my `onBackPressed` is doing what it should be...

Answer (score 4):

**You forgot**

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

**Just use below code**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: If I use this, when pressing back it still goes to a black screen and I have to press back again.

Comment: So after starting `Play` Activity from First Activity , just call `finish()`   i.e `startActivity(...) ; finish()`

Comment: I am doing that as well, and it still doesn't close. Could crosswalk be taking over the back button for browser history navigation?

Comment: might be grabbing the back preseed

Comment: seems like I had to add `onKeyDown` and place `finish()` in there similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2478869/1778465

Comment: Yes,  you have to

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(a);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to call the `super method` in your `onBackPressed()`, or if you want to go back to the previous activity, to bring to front the other activity in your `onBackPressed()`, and then, finish your `Activity` like this :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent main = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
    main.putFlags(Intent.ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT); // Or something like this, I dont really remember the flag name
    startActivity(main);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write this command when you want to exit :

```
overridePendingTransition ( 0 , 0 );
super.finish ( );
super.onStop ( );
super.onDestroy ( );
overridePendingTransition ( 0 , 0 );
```